# Why does Django create an index for ForeignKey with db_constraint=False

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to shard my database so I can't use foreign key constraints. I have following models

```
from django.db import models


class A(models.Model):
    b_one_to_one = models.OneToOneField(
        'B', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, db_constraint=False, null=True
    )

    b_one_to_many_null = models.ForeignKey(
        'B', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, db_constraint=False, null=True,
        related_name='+'
    )
    b_one_to_many_nothing = models.ForeignKey(
        'B', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_constraint=False,
        related_name='+'
    )


class B(models.Model):
    pass
```

`python manage.py makemigrations` command generates following sql code

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model A
--
CREATE TABLE `a` (`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
--
-- Create model B
--
CREATE TABLE `b` (`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
--
-- Add field b_one_to_many_nothing to a
--
ALTER TABLE `a` ADD COLUMN `b_one_to_many_nothing_id` integer NOT NULL;
--
-- Add field b_one_to_many_null to a
--
ALTER TABLE `a` ADD COLUMN `b_one_to_many_null_id` integer NULL;
--
-- Add field b_one_to_one to a
--
ALTER TABLE `a` ADD COLUMN `b_one_to_one_id` integer NULL UNIQUE;
CREATE INDEX `a_b_one_to_many_nothing_id_4fca4209` ON `a` (`b_one_to_many_nothing_id`);
CREATE INDEX `a_b_one_to_many_null_id_e498aa17` ON `a` (`b_one_to_many_null_id`);
COMMIT;
```

I understand that Django might want to create an index for `b_one_to_many_null` field due to `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` setting, but I don't understand why there is a need for an index for `b_one_to_many_nothing` field.

Is there a way to turn this automatic index creation off or it's just a Django bug?

I'm using Django 1.11.5.

Comment: Try `db_index=False` - based [this docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#db-index)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @dahrens I reread [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) and it says

> A database index is automatically created on the ForeignKey. You can
>   disable this by setting db_index to False. You may want to avoid the
>   overhead of an index if you are creating a foreign key for consistency
>   rather than joins, or if you will be creating an alternative index
>   like a partial or multiple column index.